# Проверка заполнения файла данными из второго файла, вывод этих данных из второго файла

Tags: java

В тестовом задании необходимо создать два файла. Первый файл заполнить после создания, и затем эти данные скопировать из первого файла во второй. С созданием файлов и переносом данных вроде разобралась, но как проверить то что эти данные перенесены во второй файл (как их вывести)? Заренее спасибо :)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        File file1 = new File("test1.txt");
        File file2 = new File("test2.txt");
        try {

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
bufferedWriter.write("this is test");
BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader((new FileReader(file1)));
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter2= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
String  b;
while ((b = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    bufferedWriter2.write(b);
    b=bufferedReader.readLine();
    System.out.println(b);
}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала используйте try-with-resources, далее вы открываете поток и для чтения и для записи одного и тоже файла сразу (так делать не надо), сделайте последовательно, запишите свои данные в первый файл, и потом этот поток закрывается (из-за конструкции try-with-resources), и потом же открыть поток для чтения первого файла и поток для записи во второй.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        File file1 = new File("test1.txt");
        File file2 = new File("test2.txt");

        try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1))) {
            bufferedWriter.write("this is test");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }

        try(BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader((new FileReader(file1)));
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter2= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2))){
            String  b;
            while ((b = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(b);
                bufferedWriter2.write(b);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!